# How to define nationality based on countryCode

Tags: php, locale

At the moment we are using

> http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplayregion.php

to display a country based on a 2-digit stored `countryCode` and

> http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplaylanguage.php

to show a nationality based on Language. But apparently this is not really reliable as the same country code can trigger different results. For example `CO` returns for region `Colombia` (ok!) but for Language `Corsican` (not ok). My question now is: Is there any way to map automatically regions to nationality (e.g. `Spain -> Spanish, UK -> British, Colombia -> Spanish`)? Or what would be the best way to do such a thing (it is a requirement to get it from this 2-digit country code).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use zend locale library:

```
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.locale.functions.html
```